# Clone Facebook wall posting via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would like to mimic Facebook's functionality where when you attach a link, it will read the meta data and image automatically:

[image]

[image]

Anyone know how to accomplish this interface functionality with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not reading meta data of the image, it's reading actual data from the page. It does this, probably, with cURL:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

tutorial:
http://phpsense.com/php/php-curl-functions.html

You can't do cross domain scripting with JavaScript so you will have to use a server side language such as PHP and then have PHP crawl the page and find the main content area of the description of the page... Hope that helps :\ it's not really a front end type of thing.